# Is here some use of information provided in Android Keystore? Is it even readable after we sign the app?

Tags: android, apk, alias, keystore

Eclipse ask for following information when creating the keystore,

```
First and Last Name:
Organizational Unit:
Organization:
City or Location:
State or Province:
Country Code (XX):
```

Wondering if correctness of this information really matters?

Is it even possible to extract this info from APK by any tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Its just like licensing or encrypting your code & its identity with some information which will have to be same from now on for future & further references for the current application.**

**This keystore will bind to your application on Google Play Store once you upload it and from that day who'll need this keystore to rebind and upload its updated versions.**

This information is readable when you try to use this keystore with the `keytool` command via Java.

Comment: So, if I give apk to somebody, they can read this data? (First and Last name, Organization etc)
how?

Comment: @Umair You can't read this data from APK, you have to use Keystore file to read info stored in it.

Comment: Just remember one thing, once you have created it via Signing App. Do keep it safe else you'll not be able to upload it next version.

Comment: I know about keeping it safe and updating the app thing. Ok i tell you complete scenario. I m working for a big enterprise. So before creating APK i m thinking to put correct info in keystore for which I will have to request the PM. and I m sure I will receive a counter question that if this info is useful. Or can someone extract (by any tool) this info from APK. This is my question

Comment: As per my knowledge I don't think any tool can extract keystore information from an APK, as keystore helps to bind an application and the information is just available in keystore file only. In this case, APK is just left with all generated keys by keystore. If we extract an APK in future to extract its code out of it, it won't show any information regarding its keystore file which is last used with it.